# Schema issue after db restore

Tags: sql-server

Kind of stumped on this one, maybe someone can shed a little light. I have a sql db with two different apos that access that db, I had to move the db onto a different server, when I restored the db and recreated the users and repaired the orphaned accounts, it broke a schema on one specific table inside the db, every thing else works fine. there is one table named like db_owner.sometable, first app can access it but the second can't, if I change it to say dbo.sometable, the second app works but the first one doesn't. I have tried changing the schemas around for the users with no luck with any combination. The login account for each app is different and I do know their passwords but can't change the app. How do I get the table to honor both schemas? This all worked fine on the original server, any thoughts are much appreciated, been pounding my head on this for two days now

Comment: ALTER AUTHORIZATION  might need to be applied to the whole database on the new server.   Are both logins "dbo" or "sa" like from the apps?

Comment: Is one of the two application accounts the dbo in the source system? You can check this with: `SELECT SUSER_SNAME(sid) FROM sys.[database_principals] AS [dp] WHERE name = 'dbo'`

Comment: I am not where I can look into things, I will have to wait till in the morning, but I remember one having a dbo schema and the other db_owner. Really appreciate you helping as this one has me totally stumped... I also remembering seeing that table starting out with db_owner.sometable when the rest are dbo.sometable. Don't understand why they were designed like that

Comment: On the above comments, (SQL Surfer - one is db_owner and the other is dbo, I tried to change to dbo for the user hence when I would change the schema on the table, it would run under it but no luck) (Ben Thul - when I ran your script, nothing came back on the actual db itself, but under the master db, it came back 'sa' ,both tables matches) If I look at the schemas and roles on both the old and new server, they also match)